# Align Div to centre but stay responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a personal portfolio site, I would like to centre and align my div containing the circular shape (animated in CSS) whilst remaining responsive.

I have tried flexbox, this is the code I have:

```css
:root {
  --background: #005;
  --primary: #88D5BF;
  --secondary: #5D6BF8;
  --third: #e27fcb;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f00b55;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-logo {
  width: 90px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20vmin;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: ivypresto-display, serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.blob {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
  animation: morph 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 500px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  @keyframes morph {
    0% {
      border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
    }
    50% {
      border-radius: 30% 60% 70% 40% / 50% 60% 30% 60%;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--third) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
    }
    100% {
      border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header-->
<header>
  <div class="blob">
  </div>
  <h1>Abbie is a<br>graduate UX/UI designer</h1>
</header>
```

[my example on codepen](https://codepen.io/agraylong/pen/wvdZgbR)

Comment: Can you add your HTML code too?

Comment: I have included a link to my codepen, many thanks for any advice

Comment: Please always add a [repro]. A codepen link alone is not allowed. You even get a red warning text before you post your question if you only have a codepen/fiddle link without a code sampel directly added. If your codepen link would be removed or the content change, then the question would hold no further value to the community.

Comment: Hi Tacoshy, thank you for your advice, I had included code I was using, I am new to this site so haven't fully learned guidelines. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If blob is inside header. You have stated that you wish blob to be 500px width. Try to identify various device breakpoints, (for example iPhone X = 375px, iPad Pro = 1024px).

With these breakpoints in mind, create media queries, so, for example on an iPhone class "blob" will have a height of 350px rather than 500px.

For more on media queries and how to use them, here is the link to W3, which provides a great overview: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Please note that you may have to also specifically target contents within blob, such as text, this can also be done from within the same media query.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten all about media queries for responsive design. I'm still struggling to position div containing blob in centre but will do some reading up.

Comment: No problem, If it's still giving you hassle just reply here and I can help further, the best way overall to learn though is to figure 99% out by yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I am studying web development (Year 1) but have been off studies for a year due to covid, so I need to do some brushing up. I will keep at it and reply back when I'm truly stumped. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding it correctly. You want to center the blue blob in the middle with the text over it right? As john already wrote in the answer. You need to change the height and width of the blob with media queries. If you want to change the position of the blob just change:

```
    .blob {
      left: 0;  
      right: 20%; <--- more left
    }
```

```css
:root {
    --background: #005;
    --primary: #88D5BF;
    --secondary: #5D6BF8;
    --third: #e27fcb;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f00b55;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20vmin;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: ivypresto-display, serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.blob {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
  animation: morph 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 500px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  
  

@keyframes morph {
    0% {
              border-radius:  60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
              background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
      } 
      
      50% {
              border-radius:  30% 60% 70% 40% / 50% 60% 30% 60%;
              background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--third) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
      }
    
      100% {
          border-radius:  60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
          background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--primary) 0%, var(--secondary) 100%);
      } 
  }

}
```

```html
    <!-- Header-->
    <header>
      <div class="blob">
          </div>
          <h1>Abbie is a<br>graduate UX/UI designer</h1>
        </header>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, thank you for looking over my question and giving a clear answer to resolve. I am going to do some revision on media queries for sure. Appreciated